# How to keep edgecolor for shapefile but make fill transparent matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, shapefile

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to only include a border around a shapefile? I am layering shapefiles over each other on my graphs and I want a border showing an area inside the base shapefile but don't want it to be filled. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STgjx.png) is what my maps currently look like.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged geopandas, you can plot boundaries directly from the geodataframe.
`gdf.boundary.plot(color='k')`

See plotting documentation, it's about halfway down: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html